# How to do dynamic node selection in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-deployment

```
if (Platform.equals("Dev")) {
  return ["inc1dev", "inc2dev", "inc3dev"]

} else if (Platform.equals("PreProd")) {
  return ["inc1pp", "inc2pp"]

} else if (Platform.equals("Metro")) {
  return ["inc1m", "inc2m"]

} else {
  return ["Unknown state"]
}
```

my requirement is that I have to select dynamic nodes one at a time and need listing of all the nodes present , here is screenshot attached for more detailed explanation:-
[here in this image the demo list of servers is coming,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5SmT.png)

currently its hard coded but I need dynamic listing as I have approx. 500 server list and its not possible to hard code the same.

i have searched a lot got few links but got no success. 
can any one please guide what will be the correct solution for this.

any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about the [Active Choices Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice), which lets you run bits of Groovy to determine what should be shown in a parameter drop-down, this should return a list of all agents in the system:

```
jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.nodes.collect { it.name }
```

Comment: it.name --- is this the file name??

Comment: No, it's the variable holding the node value, each time that the closure is executed.